# How "Park"/"square" (view image) is translated in Latin Language please?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, meaning

[image: Park]Park, small street square, with some threes, banks and water in the middle.

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_CGOn7X3hBUU/TGbpp3dRQ5I/AAAAAAAABZk/AQ8F0yziEJg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/100_5375.JPG

http://www.eladanbuenosayres.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/plsazoleta.jpg

Answer (score 5):

It's helpful to give a vocabulary for parks, since there are many kinds of parks.

Park vocabulary:

1. *hortus, horti* ("garden") can refer to a park. A *hortus* is often enclosed, sometimes by colonnades.
2. *paradisus, paradisi* can refer to a park or an orchard.
3. *campus, campi* can refer to an open field.
4. *silva, silvae* refers to a forest.

I think it's appropriate to use *hortus, horti* to describe the parks seen in your images, since these images depict city gardens.

Answer (score 2):

For how much I know of english, in the photo it's a "square", not a "park". Though a square may have fountains and trees, it doesn't make it a park, and certainly, in the photo, it's a square, not a park.
Quicherat, for "place - espace libre entouré de maisons" (ie open space surrounded by buildings), gives "plătĕa". In the photo, we have a "platea".

Answer (score 1):

The English “park” derives, via French, from late Latin particus, “enclosed cultivated space”, attested since the 8th century. It might also serve your purposes, assuming you are not too fussy as far as latinitas is concerned.

Comment: Your approach would be unadvisable enough if this etymology was correct but the word barely attesed; but this etymology is [surely incorrect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/park#Etymology) while the word is [not attested](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/particus) - *pund*brech refers to the **animal pound.** It isn't in Niermeyer either.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian. There are better sources than wiktionary. I have consulted CNRTL and DWDS.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is possible. CNRTL [correctly gives](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/parc) the same etymology as wiktionary. DWDS [doesn't say anything](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Park#etymwb-1) on the origin of the Latin word. Wiktionary uses these sources and more in giving its etymologies; they're more detailed when it comes to individual language histories, but not more factually correct.